# Determine which link submitted the form

Tags: jquery, forms, hyperlink, submit

I've got a page set up w/ two links that are styled to look like buttons - Save and Save & Assign:

```
<a id="submit" title="Save">Save</a>
<a id="submit_assign" title="Save & Assign">Save & Assign</a>
```

I'm using JQuery to capture the click event of each button and perform a FORM submit:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
    });

    $('#submit_assign').click(function(){
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
    });  

    $("#main_form").on("submit", function (event) {
        //call save function
        //if button clicked was submit_assign, call assign function
    });
});
```

Both the buttons will need to do the same basic functionality (ie. the save), but the Save & Assign button will need to do extra processing after a successful save. I want to determine which button caused the form submit so I can use it to see if the extra processing is needed. My first instinct is to try and pass a variable through the submit function call in the clicks, but I'm not sure how to access it in the actual submit function.

Comment: You are handling the submit in javascript then? I see no advantage to using the 'submit' event at all. Why not just have `$('#submit').click(function(){mysave();});` and `$('#submit_assign').click(function(){mysaveandassign();});` and write two different javascript functions `mysave` and `mysaveandassign`? (one of them might call the other after doing something.

Comment: Hmmm, good point. I think it might just be for consistency's sake at this point? We used to do full form submits, and we're migrating to more AJAXy stuff. I'll take a look and see if there's any reason to keep the submit. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

To do this using an `<a>` you would simply set the value of a *hidden* input in the form

```
<a id="submit_1">Submit</a>
<a id="submit_2">Save</a>


<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="" />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#submit1").on("click", function(){
    $('input[name="submit"]').val("submit");
}
$("#submit1").on("click", function(){
    $('input[name="submit"]').val("save");
}
```

---

**OLD Answer**

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="Submit" name="submit_1" value="submit_1"/>

    <input type="submit" name="submit_2" value="submit_2"/>
</form>
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_GET['submit_1'])){
    // submit one was clicked
}
elseif(isset($_GET['submit_2'])){
    /submit two was clicked
}
```

Comment: Also, I need to use javascript, not PHP (our server-side stuff is Coldfusion anyway)

Comment: This is a good solution! Works well and is backward compatible.

Comment: Gotcha, similar to Blazemonger's answer. Since that seems to be the consensus, I guess there's no way to do it without the hidden field?

Comment: Short of having two forms, no sir.

Comment: FYI for some reason it didnt work w/ `$('input[name="submit"]').val("save");` - the value wasnt being set. Changing it to `$('#submit').val("save");` worked though.

Answer (score 0):

If your submit buttons were actual `<input type="submit">` buttons, you could assign `name` and `value` attributes to them which would be passed along with the rest of the form:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
<input type="submit" id="submit_assign" name="submit" value="Save and Assign">
```

Otherwise, why not just create new `<input type="hidden">` form elements before processing the submission?

```
$('#submit_assign').click(function(){
    var hidden = '<input type="hidden" name="something" value="somethingelse">';
    $(this).parents('form').append(hidden).submit();
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't make them inputs. For your second option, I assume I'd just check for the presence of the hidden input? Or I guess I could always have the hidden there, and just change it's value on the click...

Comment: Either way -- depends on how your server-side code looks. I would first check for the existence of the form variable, then check its value.